# Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to type 'Bool'

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble with initialising a Bool, it keeps giving me errors and I can't seem to find the solution. The error I'm getting with the below code is "Cannot assign value of type 'Binding' to type 'Bool'"

Any ideas?

```
struct ProfileView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ProfileViewModel
@Binding var isFollowed: Bool

init(user: User) {
    self.viewModel = ProfileViewModel(user: user)
    // error below
    self.isFollowed = $isFollowed
    // error above
}
```

Comment: Why is it not nested as `ProfileView.Model`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not clear what you want to do, but the `$` notation is when you pass a property wrapper, such as `@State` or `@Published` *to someone else*.

For example if you want to initialize your `@Binding` property with some value passed on initialization:

First you need a corresponding argument in the init, and you initialize its value by using the "special" syntax with underscore:

```
init(...,
     isFollowed: Binding<Bool>) {
    
    // This is how binding is initialized
    self._isFollowed = isFollowed
```

Now we assume that some other class or struct (lets call it `Other`), which has some sort of state or published property:

```
@Published var isProfileFollowed = false
```

So from that `Other` class/struct you can create an instance of `ProfileView` like this:

```
ProfileView(...,
            isFollowed: $isProfileFollowed)
```

That is not just passing a *current* value of `isProfileFollowed`, but binding a `isFollowed` of `ProfileView` to `isProfileFollowed` of class/struct `Other`, so that any change in `isProfileFollowed` is also visible to a binded property `isFollowed`.

So this is just an explanation of what's not working.